# PWA theme color not applied to status bar on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I opened the [pokedex](https://pokedex.org/) progressive web app in chrome on my phone Android. After installing the PWA app on my home screen and launching it, I noticed that the status bar color is not using the theme color specified in the app and instead seems to be using the default chrome app status bar color:

[image]

- Chrome version: 89
- OS version: Android 11
- Device: Pixel XL
- PWA url: https://pokedex.org/
- Theme color: #a040a0

However, when I open the page in chrome on my macbook and install the app, then I see the correct theme color used in the status bar:

[image]

- Chrome version: 89
- OS version: macOS Big Sur 11.2.3
- Device: Macbook Pro

Here is how the theme color is specified in the manifest file:

```
"theme_color": "#a040a0",
"background_color": "#EEEEEE"
```

And here is the theme color meta tag in the HTML file:

```
<meta name=theme-color content=#a040a0>
```

Is this a bug or is this issue due to a missing configuration?

Comment: Probably chrome is in dark mode.

Try this: chrome settings -> theme -> light

Comment: Interesting! So it did not work when I tried changing Chrome theme to light, but it worked when I changed the OS theme to light! I feel like this is a bug 